# What is the best way to record a video with augmented reality

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, video-recording, ios-camera

What is the best way to record a video with augmented reality? (adding text, images logo to frames from iPhone/iPad camera)

Previously I was trying to figure out how to draw into `CIImage` ([How to draw text into CIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048860/how-to-draw-text-into-ciimage)) and convert `CIImage` back to `CMSampleBuffer` ([CIImage back to CMSampleBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053547/ciimage-back-to-cmsamplebuffer))

I almost did everything, only have problem with recording video using new `CMSampleBuffer` in `AVAssetWriterInput`

But this solution anyway isn't good at all, it eats a lot of CPU while converting `CIImage` to `CVPixelBuffer` (`ciContext.render(ciImage!, to: aBuffer)`)

So I want to stop here and find some other ways to record a video with augmented reality (for example dynamically add (draw) text inside frames while encoding video into mp4 file)

Here what I've tried and don't want to use anymore...

```
// convert original CMSampleBuffer to CIImage, 
// combine multiple `CIImage`s into one (adding augmented reality -  
// text or some additional images)
let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
let ciimage : CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
var outputImage: CIImage?
let images : Array<CIImage> = [ciimage, ciimageSec!] // add all your CIImages that you'd like to combine
for image in images {
    outputImage = outputImage == nil ? image : image.composited(over: outputImage!)
}

// allocate this class variable once         
if pixelBufferNew == nil {
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),  CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, &pixelBufferNew)
}

// convert CIImage to CVPixelBuffer
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
if let aBuffer = pixelBufferNew {
    ciContext.render(outputImage!, to: aBuffer) // >>> IT EATS A LOT OF <<< CPU
}

// convert new CVPixelBuffer to new CMSampleBuffer
var sampleTime = CMSampleTimingInfo()
sampleTime.duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer)
sampleTime.presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
sampleTime.decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
var videoInfo: CMVideoFormatDescription? = nil
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferNew!, &videoInfo)
var oBuf: CMSampleBuffer?
CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferNew!, true, nil, nil, videoInfo!, &sampleTime, &oBuf)

/*
try to append new CMSampleBuffer into a file (.mp4) using 
AVAssetWriter & AVAssetWriterInput... (I met errors with it, original buffer works ok 
- "from func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)")
*/*
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to use an Objective-C++ class (`.mm`) where we can use OpenCV and easily/fast convert from `CMSampleBuffer` to `cv::Mat` and back to `CMSampleBuffer` after processing

We can easily call Objective-C++ functions from Swift.